# QGIS expression to round to nearest 0.05

Tags: qgis, labeling, expression, round-function

I'd like to have an expression that would round to the nearest 0.05.  Can QGIS do this?

For example, if the real number was 1.4378, the label would read "1.45".

Or, if the real number was 1.4238, the label would read "1.40".

Comment: Multiply by twenty, round to integer, then divide by 20.0.

Comment: This is Vince's answer but formatted as an expression: `round("real_num" * 20, 0)/20`

Comment: Or just `"number" // 0.05 * 0.05`